# How to use variable in another windows form?

Tags: c++-cli, clr

How to use variable in another windows form? For example:
This is Form 1 event button click. After clicking th button i want to apear "num"
in textbox "Form2" form.

```
private: System::Void button_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
 int num = 10;
 Form2^ f = gcnew Form2();
 f->Show();
}
```

lets suppose that in form2 is textbox named "text"

```
private: System::Void Form2_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
text->Text = num;
}
```

Form2 doesnt see "num" variable.
Im using c++/CLI (visual studio)

Comment: This question is super thin on details.

Comment: @tadman yea but that is my actually problem.

Comment: "I have a computer problem please help" is also super thin on details, but only slightly more. Can you *explain* more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @tadman is it ok now?

Comment: It would help if you show both what you're sharing it *from* and where you're trying to share it *to*.

Comment: @tadman now, sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```cpp
private: System::Void button_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
 int num = 10;
 Form2^ f = gcnew Form2();
 f->text->Text = num.ToString();
 f->Show();
}
```

Comment: its okay but now how to "num" variable value (10) assign to for exaple: idd variable in form2?

Comment: @MichałNowakowski If `idd` is public then you can just do `f->idd = num;` But if it is not public then you need to add a public setter for it, or else a custom constructor with an input parameter that can set it.